# Hello here i am having this problem of passing multiple data In form

Tags: php, laravel

As you can see here I am looping with foreach but it only sends the one product_name (last one) of the cart, but I Want to send every product_name.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('order.store')}}">
    @csrf
    @method('POST')
            
    @foreach(Cart::content() as $item)
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="{{$item->name}}">
    @endforeach
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like `input` name as array

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_name[]" value="{{$item->name}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use an array to send multiple values using the same name attribute.

```
@foreach(Cart::content() as $item)
    <input type="hidden" name="product_name[]" value="{{$item->name}}">
@endforeach
```

this will send each product name and you have to loop through to get every one in the backend.